# Textbook in algebra leading to research

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, book-recommendation

I am searching for a book in commutative algebra with will develop theory from an undergraduate level and lead to areas of current research. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Pinter's [*A Book of Abstract Algebra (Second Edition)*](http://www.amazon.ca/Book-Abstract-Algebra-Second-Edition/dp/0486474178/ref=pd_rhf_dp_s_cp_3_1475?ie=UTF8&refRID=1QFKGETYTZ9A7RCCYWQ1) is quite good.

Answer (score 1):

You can find '[A Term of Commutative Algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/a/385313/175094)' by Allen Altman and Steven Kleiman (introduces Category Theory and has full solutions) which is a more in depth and updated version  of 'Introduction to Commutative Algebra' by Atiyah, Macdonald. After that you could try Commutative Algebra I/II by  Zariski, Samuel. Whilst simultaneously getting acquainted with Algebraic Geometry and Homological Algebra. If you think you can work through a lot by yourself and don't need solutions, skip the first book I mentioned and just start with Atiyah's book.

These books are just a basic introduction though; but they should keep you out of trouble for a while!